# Populating custom fields via. Trello API

Tags: api, trello

I'm having some trouble populating a custom field on a card via. the API. The URL I am using is:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/card/{CardID}/customField/{CustomFieldID}/item?key={Key}&token={Token}
```

The response I'm getting when making the request is a 400 code, and the response body is:

```
Invalid value for custom field type
```

The data that is being sent in the PUT request is:

```
{ "value" : { "text": "Hello, world!" }}
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here? Would you be able to point me in the right directiion? The custom field is of type: text, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you've reported trying. I just tested the following and it's working for me:

```
TRELLO_API_KEY=<your api key>
TRELLO_TOKEN=<your oauth token>
CardID=<your card id>
CustomFieldID=<your custom field id>

curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://api.trello.com/1/card/${CardID}/customField/${CustomFieldID}/item?key=${TRELLO_API_KEY}&token=${TRELLO_TOKEN}" \
-d '{"value": { "text": "Hello, world!" }}'
```

A variant that puts the key and token in the JSON also works fine:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "https://api.trello.com/1/card/${CardID}/customField/${CustomFieldID}/item \
    -d '{
      "value": { "text": "Hello, world!" },
      "key": "'"${TRELLO_API_KEY}"'",
      "token": "'"${TRELLO_TOKEN}"'"
    }'
```

And another variant translated for Node worked for me as well. Are you sure you're using correct values for key, token, cardid and customfieldid?

Comment: I believe my issue was to do with the values as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve the same problem, the request head, and content need to be json type.
Below is a python function:

```
def trelloUpdateCustomFieldItems(cardID,**kwargs):
    url = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{cardID}/customField/{list(kwargs)[0]}/item"

    payload =  json.dumps({"value": {"text": "abcd"}})

    headers = {'content-type': "application/json"}

    query = {
        'key': trelloKey,
        'token': trelloToken
     }

     response = requests.put(url, data=payload2, headers=headers, params=query)
```